# Magento2: unable to get Actual result by using getSize()?

Tags: magento2, collection

**Collection**

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
        $tagModel = $this->tagTagFactory->create();
        $this->_productCollection = $this->_productCollection
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->addTagFilter($this->getTag()->getId())
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
           // ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->setActiveFilter();


      $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => 
      $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
      $this->_productCollection->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
      return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

I am trying to get $this->_productCollection->getSize() which doesnot reflect proper result.

Comment: Did you want count of product?

Comment: Yes by using getSize()

Comment: Without  using `->addTagFilter($this->getTag()->getId())`  and check ` $this->_productCollection->getSize()` give proper  value   and  or use `$this->_productCollection->count() ` getting proper data

Comment: @AmitBera i remove ->addTagFilter($this->getTag()->getId()) but not working and i want to get value using getSize() for toolbar data

Comment: @AmitBera Can u please suggest me another solution

Comment: I'm facing the same issue; did you manage to find something ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$this->_productCollection->count()`

Comment: Yes tried but still not working. Can u suggest me some way to use getSelectCountSql()

Comment: @Parthavi is the collection returning any results? `count()` should give you the number of results returned by the collection. Can you please edit your post to include your entire class file. I'd like to see the constructor.